# Duplicates in tableview section Swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I amm trying to put some datas into categories into a tableView. Pizzas into pizza category, burgers into burger etc, but i have every item duplicate ( Look here [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmpZY.png) . What can be the problem ?

Struct :

```
struct Food {
    
    var photoKeyRestaurant: String
    var foodName: String
    var foodDescription: String
    var restaurantName: String
    var priceFood: Int
    var typeFood: String
    
    
}
```

Table View

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return food.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return food[section].foodName.count
        
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoodTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FoodTableViewCell
        
        
        
        //   cell.delegate = self
        let mancare = food[indexPath.section]
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let photoRef = storageRef.child(mancare.photoKeyRestaurant)
        cell.foodImage.sd_setImage(with: photoRef)
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = mancare.foodDescription
        cell.foodNameLabel.text = mancare.foodName
        cell.priceLabel.text = "\(mancare.priceFood) lei"
        cell.foodImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.foodImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.foodImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.foodImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.foodImage.frame.height/2
        cell.foodImage.clipsToBounds = true
        
        //Fac ca imaginea sa fie cerc  - finish
        return cell
}
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return food[section].typeFood
    }
```

If somone will ask, im retrieving the data from the firestore, but there s no problem there, because the data is retrieved succesfuly.

Anyone know what can be the problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting that your code for `cellForRowAt` never actually mentions the `indexPath.row`. It refers only to the `indexPath.section`. How can you get and display data corresponding to *this* row, which you are supposed to configure in `cellForRowAt` if you do not in some way *refer* to the question of *what* row this is?

Perhaps there is some other mechanism going on that I don't see, but it seems to me that this one fact alone explains why each section just shows the same data over and over rather than different data for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 big problems with this code.

1. You have the wrong array of data fo sections.
2. in the func  `cellForRowAt` you cant return `indexPath.section`.

**With first**. You need to use 2-dimensional arrays like:

```
var foodCategorys: [FoodCategory] = [[categoryName, Food],[categoryName, Food]]
```

So you need another struct to contain this 2-dimensional array:

```
struct FoodCategory {
    var categoryName: String
    var listFood: [Food] = [] // Food is the struct that you currently have
}
```

So the data will display in tableView is an array FoodCategory. With numberOfSections will return a count of an array FoodCategory. And numberOfRowsInSection will return a count of a listFood into FoodCatogory.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return foodCategorys.count //array of listFood
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return foodCategorys[section].listFood.count
}
```

**And second**, in `cellForRowAt`, when you want to get the index of list data. you need to call `foods[indexPath.section].listFood[indexPath.row]`. The func need `row` not `section`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoodTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FoodTableViewCell
        //cell.delegate = self
        let mancare = foods[indexPath.section].listFood[indexPath.row] //Remeber that, the array food we are using in this line is array of FoodCategory
```

I think you need to research with key word "section in uitableview swift", or watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHY09z-XS9s

So, that all. I hope you will understand how tableview and section work

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, im getting an error at declaaring foodCategorys : " Cannot find 'categoryName' in scope"

Comment: Hi, with `[[categoryName, Food],[categoryName, Food]]`, I just describe how are the 2-dimensional arrays in this case.

Comment: Hi with `[[categoryName, Food],[categoryName, Food]]`, I just describe how are the 2-dimensional arrays in this case.
You need to understand that you will display to tableView with list categories (ex: list categories have 2 item include: coffee and pizza). And with item coffee, you have the categoryName is 'Coffee' and list food in this item like: 'capuchino, expreso'. 
with TableView, `section` will show list Categories, and `row` will show list food in this Categories. If what I said confuses you then you can watch the video link and rewrite the code. it works with your case.